# Dispose singletons on application exit with Ninject

Tags: c#, ninject

I'm using Ninject for a desktop application. I'm noticing that if I exit the app, singletons that implement `IDisposable` are not being disposed.

What is the best practice for ensuring all `IDisposable` singleton objects get disposed of properly with Ninject upon exiting a desktop application?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to dispose the kernel in order to dispose the remaining cached objects.